# Check if a link is internal or external

Tags: c#, .net

Hello i am building something like a webspider in C#. In my research i came across a problem were i need to determen if a link is internal or external, inbound or outbound. So i needed to create a function to do the work for me. So i came up with the following function but i am not sure if its the best possible algorythm in order to accomplish that task. So i would like your opinions upon this problem.

I asume that links with no http:// or https:// in front of the link are internal
and if i have a domain http://www.blahblah.com then a link like test should still be internal despite the fact that it has http:// in front, but a link like http://www.somethingelse.com/?var1=http://www.blahblah.com/test is external sto i am checking the first letters only.

```
private Boolean checklinkifinternal(String link)
        {
            Boolean isinternal = false;

            if (link.IndexOf("http://") == 0 || link.IndexOf("https://") == 0)
            {
                //Then probably external
                if (link.IndexOf("http://" + UrlName) == 0 || link.IndexOf("https://" + UrlName) == 0 || link.IndexOf("http://www." + UrlName) == 0 || link.IndexOf("https://www." + UrlName) == 0)
                {
                    isinternal = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                isinternal = true;
            }

            return isinternal;
        }
```

Comment: how can you determine whether it's external/internal by the protocol it's using...?

Comment: What about http://127.0.0.1 or http://192.168.1.1 both of these are internal but would pass as external

Comment: indeed didnt think of that Lloyd

Comment: I think you need a new approach.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366343/how-can-i-determine-if-an-http-request-is-being-made-to-internal-network-or-to-t

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Uri.Compare(new Uri("google.de"), new Uri("Google.de"), UriComponents.Host, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
```

this is what i would say from the top of my head :)

Comment: as for internal/external definition. i think you refer to it as "am i still on the same site currently as i was before" and not "does this host have 2 ips that lead to the same site"

Comment: Volker Manuel yes i think this is a possible fact to. If there is 1 domain matching two ips should be the same site. Load Balance is an example of such fact?

Comment: true. than you'd have to compare the 2 ips and see if the same files exist on each host. lot's of work,i'd really go with just comparing hostnames(regardless of protocol)

Comment: mmm i think that the Uri must be a Uri type, if i grab a link like "/somelink.html" it wont recognize it as a Uri to compair it against the Domain i am crowling.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you're on a http URI, does a link to a https URI count as an internal link even if the domain name is the same? (And vice versa.) You will have to decide.

Also, your algorithm doesn't take local filesystems (using file://) into account.

Comment: yes you are correct, even thogh in file://test.zip is not something i should crowl but i do need to handle it in some way